# SQL - order by before the group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table products:

---

```
| id       | code     | active
--------------------------------
| 1        | 1111     | 0    |
| 2        | 1111     | 0    |
| 3        | 1111     | 1    |
| 4        | 2222     | 0    |
| 5        | 2222     | 1    |
| 6        | 2222     | 0    |
| 7        | 3333     | 0    |
| 8        | 3333     | 0    |
| 9        | 3333     | 0    |
--------------------------------
```

And i want to choose one record from each code. But if active = 1 then the record has priority. So i want to see:

---

```
| id       | code     | active
--------------------------------
| 3        | 1111     | 1    |
| 5        | 2222     | 1    |
| 7        | 3333     | 0    |
--------------------------------
```

I tried:

```
select * from (Select * from products order by active desc) as query group by code
```

But i doesn't work and show:

---

```
| id       | code     | active
--------------------------------
| 1        | 1111     | 0    |
| 4        | 2222     | 0    |
| 7        | 3333     | 0    |
--------------------------------
```

Anyone may help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  coalesce(min(case when active = 1 then id end), min(id)) id, code, max(active) active
from products
group by code
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select p.id, p.code, p.active
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by code order by active desc, id) rn
  from products
) p 
where p.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83974640248d2ff0a315e6308040e51c).
Results:

```
> id | code | active
> -: | ---: | -----:
>  3 | 1111 |      1
>  5 | 2222 |      1
>  7 | 3333 |      0
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! All of answers work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could use row_number function here:

```
select x.*
from
(select a.*,
       row_number() Over(partition by code order by active desc) as rownum1
from products a) x
where x.rownum1=1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.id = (select p2.id 
              from products p2
              where p2.code = p.code
              order by p2.active desc
              limit 1
             );
```

`GROUP BY` is for summarizing rows, not for selecting a particular row.

Comment: I got error: "Subquery returns more than 1 row" @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @MaronFive . . . It is fixed now.